# How to run 2 separate sql server engines on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I have a Windows server, and on this server there are many websites running and most of them connect to the installed SQL Server, some of them connect to SQL Server Express and some to local.

My issue is: there is one old website, has some programming errors which affect SQL Server performance and as a result affect all websites performance.

I can't currently fix these errors, so i want to put this website on a separate SQL Server engine.

Is that possible and how? or there is any other suggested solutions?

Update:
The issue I have is that some queries while running make the server very slow and opening SQL Server Management Studio is very slow as well.

Comment: You can install more than one instance of SQL Server on a machine. What is the nature of the performance issues?

Comment: connection not closed or very long queries, which some time fail, somethings like this.

Comment: i have on this server 2 instances, the (local) and .\sqlexpress but they affect each other performance

Comment: @AmrElGarhy You are speculating about a solution without telling us the problem. If you post a new question with an example of the error messages you see in your application, we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3):

#### Multiple installations are possible

According to the [feature matrix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), You can install up to 16 instances of SQL Server on one host. If you use Enterprise edition, you can install up to 50.

The [side-by-side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) documentation states that certain features will be shared among all instances. For example, if you install the development kit or the management tools, you will be able to use them with all instaled instances. The database engine and other instance-specific components will be logically isolated.

Run the SQL Server installer from your installation media and it will guide you through the process of creating another instance.

#### Will it solve your problem?

You haven't given us any detail about the performance problem, so it's hard to know if using a separate instance would benefit you.

If the application behaves so badly that it causes SQL Server to restart, then running a separate instance will stop the restart from affecting other applications.

If the application is executing poorly-optimized queries that result in a lot of disk scanning, then running a seperate instance is unlikely to help you, because the same hardware is shared among all instances.